# How to add section break next page using openxml?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I want to add a section break at the end of the document and add some text.

My code is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace WordDocManipulation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = @"C:\sample.docx";
            string strtxt = "Hello This is done by programmatically";      

           OpenAndAddTextToWordDocument(path,strtxt);
        }
        public static void OpenAndAddTextToWordDocument(string filepath, string txt)
        {
            /* I want to the below text to be added in the new section */ 

            // Open a WordprocessingDocument for editing using the filepath.
            WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true);

            // Assign a reference to the existing document body.
            Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

            // Add new text.
            Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
            Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));

            // Close the handle explicitly.
            wordprocessingDocument.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 15):

You need to add the section break to the section properties. You then need to append the section properties to the paragraph properties. Followed by appending the paragraph properties to a paragraph.

```
        Paragraph paragraph232 = new Paragraph();

        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties220 = new ParagraphProperties();

        SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties();
        SectionType sectionType1 = new SectionType(){ Val = SectionMarkValues.NextPage };

        sectionProperties1.Append(sectionType1);

        paragraphProperties220.Append(sectionProperties1);

        paragraph232.Append(paragraphProperties220);
```

The resulting Open XML is:

```js
  <w:p>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:sectPr>
        <w:type w:val="nextPage" />
      </w:sectPr>
    </w:pPr>
  </w:p>
```

If you create a Word document that looks the way you want the result to look, then open in it in the [Open XML Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425), you can reflect the code and see what C# code would generate the various Open XML elements you are trying to achieve.

Comment: While this DOES indeed insert a section break, there's a problem when it comes to the final document page properties. The entire document (before inserting a section break) likely has a specific `sectionProperties` entry at the end. When adding a break the pages before loose those properties. Any idea how to make sure the page properties aren't lost?

Comment: @Shaamaan If you're creating an entirely new document in OpenXML, then there will be no problem. You create a `new SectionProperties()` and `Append` your properties to it. Nothing will be overwritten. If you're trying to modify an existing document, then you will need to retrieve the exiting `SectionProperties` and either loop through them, changing what you need, or appending anything new that you like. You'd start with `var sections = docPart.Document.Descendants<SectionProperties>();` [Example available here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg308472(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

First you need to create a break paragraph

```
Paragraph PageBreakParagraph = new Paragraph(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page }));
```

Then you need to append the paragraph

```
wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(PageBreakParagraph)
```

You can also specify where to insert it, if you don't want to append it to the end by using the InsertAfter and InsertBefore methods

```
wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(PageBreakParagraph, ReferenceElement);
wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertBefore(PageBreakParagraph, ReferenceElement);
```

Edit:

This adds a page break not a section break.

Comment: This would insert a page break. Not a section break. The two are very different from one another.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice he's asking about section break. I updated the answer to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

this one will add section break at the end of the page

```
private static void AddSectionBreakToTheDocument(string fileName)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument mydoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart myMainPart = mydoc.MainDocumentPart;
        Paragraph paragraphSectionBreak = new Paragraph();
        ParagraphProperties paragraphSectionBreakProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
        SectionProperties SectionBreakProperties = new SectionProperties();
        SectionType SectionBreakType = new SectionType() { Val = SectionMarkValues.NextPage };
        SectionBreakProperties.Append(SectionBreakType);
        paragraphSectionBreakProperties.Append(SectionBreakProperties);
        paragraphSectionBreak.Append(paragraphSectionBreakProperties);
        myMainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(paragraphSectionBreak, myMainPart.Document.Body.LastChild);
        myMainPart.Document.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems it works fine, what if i want insert a Section Break to the first page (cover page) and at the end of the document, so in other words i have two section breaks to insert, in first page, and at the end of the document, your method did the second (at the end of the document)