# get start and end of each page in docx file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, openxml, docx

i want to get content of each page of DOCX file and put it to a string var. how cant i do this with JavaScript. is there any library to do this for me?

can i use open XML file for this purpose? is there any tag for start and end of each page ?

is there any suggestion for other language like PHP Python or any thing else?

i already find this document but they are not what i am looking for:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.splitpagebreakandparagraphmark.aspx
2. [Create page break using OpenXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795315/create-page-break-using-openxml)
3. [How to add section break next page using openxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040613/how-to-add-section-break-next-page-using-openxml)
4. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/12e84734-b7c9-4b7b-9dbc-d8730e779b57/determine-the-page-breaks-in-open-xml-document-for-docx-file?forum=oxmlsdk

Comment: Strongly suggest that you find another approach to solve your problem that does not involve pagination, which is dependent upon the particulars of the rendering engine used and which is not stored reliably in DOCX files anyway.  See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40139811/290085) for further details.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you actually want to read the text of the DOCX file. How to do that has been answered elsewhere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440170/get-docx-file-contents-using-javascript-jquery . If not and you actually need the content per-page, please refer to the first comment here